# converting xml to Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, xml, pandas

I have a large number of XML files ~ 3000. Each xml file consists of a single user tweets. The file name is the user ID. I want to create a pandas dataframe that consists of 3000 rows and two columns. One column is `user_id`, and the other column is `user tweets`.

I was able to extract the content of one sample XML file and save it in a list.

```
#parse the xml file 
mytree=ET.parse('1a6446f74e20c558a2cef325394499.xml')
myroot=mytree.getroot()

tweet_list=[element.text for element in myroot.iter('document')]
```

Sample of my xml

```
<author lang="en">
    <documents>
        <document><![CDATA[I see my page views are up 433% of late....now that definitely has my attention.To all you lovely and supportive... ]]></document>
        <document><![CDATA[Howdy fans - I've moved another 35 spots today,up the "Global Reverbnation Country Charts",getting closer to my goal.]]></document>
        <document><![CDATA[happy Memorial Day weekend this is a song I wrote for the veterans that suffer from p,d,s,d - Watch on N1M ]]></document>
    </documents>
</author>
```

I want to apply this code to all my xml files that are located in one directory. And then convert the lists to be rows in a data frame.

I tried this code to get the content of the files but I can't get passed `myroot`

```
import os
path = './data'

    for filename in os.listdir(path):
        if not filename.endswith('.xml'): 
            continue
        fullname = os.path.join(path, filename)
        #print(fullname)
        mytree = ET.parse(fullname)
        myroot=mytree.getroot()
```

Any tip would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- The following code will use [`Path.rglob`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.rglob) from the [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#module-pathlib) module to find all files
- This will create a single dataframe with tweets from all `user_id` files
- As an example, with your sample data in three files named `test_00.xml`, `test_01.xml`, and `test_02.xml`, in a directory named `xml`
- `2.94 s ± 20.1 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)` for 4640 files, each containing 3 tweets.

### Option 1: Outputs 1 tweet per row

```py
from pathlib import Path
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import pandas as pd

# path to top directory
p = Path('xml')

# find all files
files = p.rglob('*.xml')

# create dataframe
df_list = list()
for file in files:
    mytree=ET.parse(file)
    myroot=mytree.getroot()
    tweet_list=[element.text for element in myroot.iter('document')]
    df_list.append(pd.DataFrame({'user_id': file.stem, 'tweets': tweet_list}))

df = pd.concat(df_list).reset_index(drop=True)
```

#### Output 1

```py
 user_id                                                                                                                 tweets
 test_00   I see my page views are up 433% of late....now that definitely has my attention.To all you lovely and supportive... 
 test_00  Howdy fans - I've moved another 35 spots today,up the "Global Reverbnation Country Charts",getting closer to my goal.
 test_00            happy Memorial Day weekend this is a song I wrote for the veterans that suffer from p,d,s,d - Watch on N1M 
 test_01   I see my page views are up 433% of late....now that definitely has my attention.To all you lovely and supportive... 
 test_01  Howdy fans - I've moved another 35 spots today,up the "Global Reverbnation Country Charts",getting closer to my goal.
 test_01            happy Memorial Day weekend this is a song I wrote for the veterans that suffer from p,d,s,d - Watch on N1M 
 test_02   I see my page views are up 433% of late....now that definitely has my attention.To all you lovely and supportive... 
 test_02  Howdy fans - I've moved another 35 spots today,up the "Global Reverbnation Country Charts",getting closer to my goal.
 test_02            happy Memorial Day weekend this is a song I wrote for the veterans that suffer from p,d,s,d - Watch on N1M
```

### Option 2: Outputs 1 row per `user_id`

```py
p = Path('xml')
files = p.rglob('*.xml')

df_list = list()
for file in files:
    mytree=ET.parse(file)
    myroot=mytree.getroot()
    tweet_list = [[element.text for element in myroot.iter('document')]]
    df_list.append(pd.DataFrame({'user_id': file.stem, 'tweets': tweet_list }))

df = pd.concat(df_list).reset_index(drop=True)
```

#### Output 2

```py
 user_id                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      tweets
 test_00  [I see my page views are up 433% of late....now that definitely has my attention.To all you lovely and supportive... , Howdy fans - I've moved another 35 spots today,up the "Global Reverbnation Country Charts",getting closer to my goal., happy Memorial Day weekend this is a song I wrote for the veterans that suffer from p,d,s,d - Watch on N1M ]
 test_01  [I see my page views are up 433% of late....now that definitely has my attention.To all you lovely and supportive... , Howdy fans - I've moved another 35 spots today,up the "Global Reverbnation Country Charts",getting closer to my goal., happy Memorial Day weekend this is a song I wrote for the veterans that suffer from p,d,s,d - Watch on N1M ]
 test_02  [I see my page views are up 433% of late....now that definitely has my attention.To all you lovely and supportive... , Howdy fans - I've moved another 35 spots today,up the "Global Reverbnation Country Charts",getting closer to my goal., happy Memorial Day weekend this is a song I wrote for the veterans that suffer from p,d,s,d - Watch on N1M ]
```

### Option 3: Using [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) - 1 row per tweet

- This solution is suggested by [sammywemmy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7175713/sammywemmy)
- The output `df` is the same as `Output 1`
- `806 ms ± 14.5 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)` for 4640 files, each containing 3 tweets.

```py
from collections import defaultdict
from pathlib import Path
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import pandas as pd

# path to top directory
p = Path('xml')

# find all files
files = p.rglob('*.xml')

box = defaultdict(list)
for file in files:
    root = ET.parse(file).getroot()
    for element in root.iter("document"):
        box[file.stem].append(element.text)

# get the final data into a dataframe
# use T (transpose) and stack
df = pd.DataFrame(pd.DataFrame(box).T.stack()).reset_index(level=0).reset_index(drop=True).rename(columns={'level_0': 'user_id', 0: 'tweets'})
```

### Option 4: Using [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) - 1 row per `user_id`

- The output `df` is the same as `Output 2`

```py
p = Path('xml')
files = p.rglob('*.xml')

box = defaultdict(list)
for file in files:
    root = ET.parse(file).getroot()
    box[file.stem].append([element.text for element in myroot.iter('document')])

df = pd.DataFrame(pd.DataFrame(box).T.stack()).reset_index(level=0).reset_index(drop=True).rename(columns={'level_0': 'user_id', 0: 'tweets'})
```

Comment: @leena Sorry, final update above.  I updated `Option 2` to be less complicated and added `Option 4`.  Your choice.  Good Luck.

Comment: Thank you. The fourth options is the best one. I am grateful.

Answer (score 1):

I've created a package because I have a similar use case.

```
pip install pandas_read_xml
```

Here is how you might use it.
Say all the xml files are in authors.zip file.

```
import pandas_read_xml as pdx

df = pdx.read_xml('authors.zip')
```

Although, that xml format is not one that I have anticipated, so may need to check out what it does.